# Google App Engine performs different from its local appserver

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web-scraping, google-search

The following function will extract URLs form Google search result. It works well in `dev_appserver`(localhost) but when I deployed it on Google App Engine it show some Error.

**Program:**

```
def googleSearch(keyword):
    from re import findall
    from urllib2 import build_opener
    from urllib import quote, unquote
    urlregex = r'<a[ ]href="/url\?q=(http://.+?)[&]'
    searchURL = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + quote(keyword, safe = '') # https will exclude Cached results
    #Google
    opener = build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
    pagesource = opener.open(searchURL).read()
    result = findall(urlregex, pagesource)
    print result
    resultlist = []
    for url in result:
        resultlist.append(unquote(url))
    resultlist = sorted(set(resultlist), key=resultlist.index)
    return resultlist
```

**GAE Error:**

```
Internal Server Error

The server has either erred or is incapable of performing the requested operation.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~crawlnsearch/1.370098233684025667/main.py", line 56, in get
    result = googleSearch(q)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~crawlnsearch/1.370098233684025667/goosearch.py", line 15, in googleSearch
    pagesource = opener.open(searchURL).read()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 442, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 629, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable
```

Did any one know solution for this problem.

Comment: Have you tried to point your code to another page, i.e yahoo, to see if you get the same error ?

Comment: @Thomas I also written a function for YouTube search and it works well with GAE.